# Could not deduce (k2 ~ k4) from the context (Ord k2) during map reduce

Tags: haskell, mapreduce

I'm doing a map reduce in haskell and I was given some code to start off with but I'm getting some compiler errors that I don't understand of the form:

Could not deduce (k2 ~ k4)
from the context (Ord k2)

Here's the code:

```
import Data.Map (Map,empty,insertWith,mapWithKey,filterWithKey,toList)


mapReduce :: forall k1 k2 v1 v2 v3. Ord k2
            => (k1 -> v1 -> [(k2,v2)])
            -> (k2 -> [v2] -> Maybe v3)
            -> Map k1 v1
            -> Map k2 v3

mapReduce mAP rEDUCE = reducePerKey . groupByKey . mapPerKey
    where
        mapPerKey :: Map k1 v1 -> [(k2,v2)]
        mapPerKey = 
            concat 
          . map (uncurry mAP)
          . toList

        groupByKey :: [(k2,v2)] -> Map k2 [v2]
        groupByKey = foldl insert empty
            where
                insert dict (k2,v2) = insertWith (++) k2 [v2] dict

        reducePerKey :: Map k2 [v2] -> Map k2 v3
        reducePerKey = 
            mapWithKey unJust 
          . filterWithKey isJust
          . mapWithKey rEDUCE
            where
                isJust k (Just v) = True
                isJust k Nothing  = False
                unJust k (Just v) = v
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe show us the full error? And perhaps the full code too, since there isn't a single `k4` in what you showed?

Comment: Also any extensions that are specified on the command line... in particular, is `ScopedTypeVariables` enabled?

Comment: @alternative The `k4` is just a result of GHC's habit of disambiguating different versions of identically named type variables by adding/incrementing numbers to/in them. Which doesn't fit so well with using numbered type variables in code, I see. (You can see the errors if you enable `RankNTypes` but *not* `ScopedTypeVariables`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NathanHowell and alternative  said, it is important that you post the actual code, error, and command for compilation or interpretation.  In this case you are using Glasgow Haskell and, it appears, trying to use features of the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension but without actually enabling the extension.

Just include:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

At the top of your source file, or use `-XScopedTypeVariables` at the command line, and things work fine.  Without scoped type variables the inner type vars of `k2` (those for the reducePerKey and groupByKey) are different variables than the `k2` for the `mapReduce` function.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of details, the problem was the lack of the ScopedTypeVariables flags. I'm still a novice when it comes to Haskell. All is well now, thanks for the answers :)